# How to export JAVA_HOME in Lambda Linux Docker image?

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ec2, container

I'm using the Lambda Linux AWS image.  I'm trying to install Atlassian Bamboo that requires JAVA_HOME to be exported.  I've been able to install java and verify it is installed properly.  I can't get the JAVA_HOME to export though.

I created a file named jdk_home.sh in /etc/profile.d

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin
```

I have done this successfully on another AWS instance, but not in a Docker container.  I've also executed the script directly and it still doesn't export.

What else can I do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Dockerfile for the container, you can specify various environment variables to be persisted through containers.

For example, in this case, you would add this snippet before the `CMD` entrypoint:

```
[...]
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java/bin
[...]
```

See this link for more details: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env